# Find and replace using existing word .doc with .net core

Tags: c#, ms-word, filestream

I'm trying to find and replace specific words/strings in a word document template i have created and added to my .net core project.

I'm currently using NPOI to do this but I cant seem to figure it out as my C# knowledge is not great!

In theory I want to read the ready made .docx template and then replace what I need to and then save it.

I've tried everything I could think of but still not working.

Here the code i'm left with:

```
var docUrl = @"App_Data/Document_Template.docx";

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(docUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(file);

            // get the document template using docUrl and replace string with another string.

            doc.Write(file);

        }
```

Any help would be awesome as i've spent so much time researching and trying to implement this and just not having any luck!

Comment: Using a filestream is never going to work since it has no knowledge of the underlying filetype. You probably want to read up on Word Interop. With the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly, you can get the contents and formatting from the document..

Comment: Do you know of any examples using Word Interop to do this?

Comment: Just use Google...:)

Comment: `.docx` can be extracted like a zip file. It contains a bunch of `.xml` files which may be parsable by standard C# libraries. You should be able to compress it back into a `.docx` file after making the desired updates.

Comment: Opemxmlpowertools can help you [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For replace specific word(s) in MS Word, first you should add the below reference from nuget:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

This sample code replace specified string with another one:

```
namespace MSWordReplacement
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application app = new Application();
            Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Sample.docx");

            // Assign a search string to a variable.
            object findText = "Find me.";

            // Clear formatting from previous searches.
            app.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();

            if (app.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText))
            {
                // Replace new text.
                app.Selection.Text = "You found me!";
            }
            else
            {
                // Do somthing else.
            }

            doc.Close(true);
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

For warning you should know this package is working but it may not be fully compatible with dot net core!

For more information use this link: [Programmatically search for and replace text in documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-search-for-and-replace-text-in-documents/)

Comment: Thanks Sajad. this worked so have accepted this as the correct answer. Have done a bit of research and wondered if it would be better to use DocX for this? Do you know DocX and if so, would this be a better option for me or not?

Comment: This kind of usage named **"Word Automation"** that you can find a lot of documents in web to get how it's working.
Generally, you can do most of MS Word capabilities in word automation. So if you are not very well in C#, Choose the packages that you can find more documents whole the web.

Comment: Interop will work on local but cannot work on docker or azure!